Showing Transience of Success Run chain
A success run chain $X_{n}$ is a markov chain on $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that the transition probabilities are $p_{i,0}:=1-p_{i}:=q_{i}$ for all $i\geq 0$ and $p_{i,i+1}:=p_{i}$.
I saw here that in a success run chain, if $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}p_{i}>0$, then the chain is transient and vice versa.
But I could not find a proof of this fact. I am trying to prove it on my own.

My attempt
I know that $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}p_{i}>0\iff\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q_{i}<\infty$. Let $\tau_{N}=\inf\{n\geq 1:X_{n}=N\}$ and $\tau_{N,0}=\inf\{n>\tau_{N}:X_{n}=0\}$ . I can show inductively that $P(\tau_{N}<\infty)=1$ for all $N$ by showing $E(\tau_{N})<\infty$.
Then $\tau_{N}$ and $\tau_{N,0}$ are stopping times.
Let $h_{k}^{0}=P(\text{hitting time of $0$ starting at state $k$ is finite})$. We have $h_{k}^{0}=q_{k}+(1-q_{k})h_{k+1}^{0}=h_{k+1}^{0}+q_{k}(1-h_{k+1}^{0})\geq h_{k+1}^{0}$. Thus $h_{k}^{0}$ is non-increasing in $k$.
We have $1-h_{k}^{0}=\prod_{i=k}^{\infty}p_{i}\geq \prod_{i=0}^{\infty}p_{i}$
and the RHS is strictly positive (and uniformly so for all $k$) if $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}p_{i}>0\iff \sum_{k}q_{k}<\infty$.
Thus $h_{k}^{0}<1$ for each $k$.
This means $(h_{k}^{0})_{k}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence in $k$ (due to the relation $h_{k}^{0}=h_{k+1}^{0}+(1-h_{k+1}^{0})q_{k}>h_{k+1}^{0}$). Thus, as $h_{k}^{0}$ is bounded below by $0$, it converges to $0$ as $k\to\infty$
Now $P(\text{0 is hit infinitely often})\leq P(\tau_{N,0}<\infty)$
Now by strong markov property at $\tau_{N}$,  $P(\tau_{N,0}<\infty)=q_{N}+p_{N}h_{N+1}^{0}$ and the RHS now tends to $0$ as $N\to\infty$.

Reverse direction Suppose the chain is transient and $\sum_{k}q_{k}=\infty$, then $\prod_{i}p_{i}=0$.
So, let $Z$ be the last time zero is hit.
So $$P(Z\leq N)\leq P(\text{all steps after time N is positive})\leq \sum_{M=0}^{\infty}P(X_{N}=M)\cdot(\prod_{k=M}^{\infty}p_{k})$$
But for each $M$, $P(X_{N}=M)\cdot (\prod_{k=M}^{\infty}p_{k})=0$, hence the sum is also $0$.
But $P(Z<\infty)=\lim_{N\to\infty}P(Z\leq N)=0$. This means that $0$ is a recurrent state and since the chain is irreducible, all states are recurrent.

Question: I request someone to verify my attempt. I also want to know if there is a shorter or more elegant way(not necessarily shorter) to prove this. Any help is appreciated.


I don't see a flaw in your attempt. Recurrence/Transience just depends on whether $h_{i}^{0}$ is $1$ or not. The rest of the proof can be omitted if you know the result that if $P_{j}(T_{i}<\infty)=1$ for all $i,j$ in the state space, then the chain is recurrent and vice versa.

I see. Thanks @Mr.GandalfSauron
